# Ajax - modify data string before get

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'report.php',
        data: ({url: href})
 });

alert(href);
```

href = https://website.com

how do i remove the https from the url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Javascript's replace function on href.

```
href.replace('https://','');
```